# How to extract address string from boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::local_endpoint().address()

Tags: tcp, boost-asio, endpoint

I am using [boost::asio::ip::tcp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html). Once connection is established between my TCP client and TCP server, I want to get the `local_endpoint`'s address as string, and the `remote_endpoint`'s address as string on both sides.

```
auto localAddress = tcpSocket.local_endpoint().address().to_string();
auto remoteAddress = tcpSocket-remote_endpoint().address().to_string();
```

But I am confused. In some cases I get `127.0.0.1` and in some cases I get `::ffff:127.0.0.1`. Is `::ffff:127.0.0.1` V6 and `127.0.0.1` is V4? I just need the IP address that is `127.0.0.1`.

I can do a substring extraction to get the `127.0.0.1` piece as well. But I want to know if there a `boost::asio` standard technique to extract/convert `::ffff:127.0.0.1` to `127.0.0.1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ip::address` stores either IPv4 or IPv6 address. You can check what kind of address is stored by `is_v6()` or `is_v4()` methods.

Addresses of IPv6 are much more than IPv4, so only some subset of IPv6 addresses can be mapped into IPv4.

When you have `IPv6` you could use `is_v4_mapped` method to check this map `ip6 -> ip4` is possible. If so, just use `operator<<` overload to extract IPv4 in string format:

Example code:

```
boost::asio::ip::address addr{boost::asio::ip::make_address("::ffff:127.0.0.1")};
if (addr.is_v6())
{
    boost::asio::ip::address_v6 ipv6 = addr.to_v6();

    if (ipv6.is_v4_mapped())
    {
        auto ipv4 = ipv6.to_v4();
        std::ostringstream os;
        os << ipv4;

        std::string str = os.str(); // 127.0.0.1
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35e2ce908eb0462c)

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm. Thanks for that explanation. I understand this much better now.